# Filipino national getting a visa via a British partner

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

My British partner would like me to visit him for the Christmas holidays this year.

We have been in a relationship since April of 2017, and he has visited me in the Philippines and I have also spoken to his parents online.

He is financially capable and willing to cover all the costs for my stay with him in the UK.

We would like to know what documents are required from him and what type of visa best suits my situation; along with any specific requirements that I would need to fulfill for the visa application.

Comment: How long to you intend to visit? Eg just a short visit, or something longer like living with your boyfriend or looking for work?

Comment: Also you may want to consider rewriting your post a bit to focus on the facts rather than your personal story in detail. This site is a "Q&A" format which works best with direct and focused question. (That said, welcome. :-) )

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for taking a time to read everything what I have written, my intention was to really tell our situation so that you guys could profile us and arrived any suggestion from there, but thank you for the tips I will make sure to make it as a "Q and A" format next time. I intend to with my boyfriend for just 3 months and then be back in the Philippines since it is what usually Embassy would grant for General Tourist Visa but it would also be best if we could be together longer than 3 months if there is anyway.

Comment: I am not looking forward of working in UK just yet since our priority now is for me to get to the UK and meet his family and to be with him as longest possible. Yes maybe in the future once we officially live together.

Comment: One potential issue I see is your ties to Philippines - in my opinion someone who has serious ties to the country/economy/community would find it difficult to spend three months in another country. So you might have better chance to succeed by asking for (and staying) shorter period.

Comment: Hi George! Would you suggest to secure a paper from my company saying that they are permitting me to be away for 3 months? Yes it is difficult to be a away for three months from your country if you have serious ties. The only thing that I can consider and could show to the Embassy which would serve as my ties from my country are my work, land property and house that me and my sister is currently building.

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit to get to the facts of the matter as is relates to travel. You should also know that the UK does not discriminate based on your sexual preference.

Comment: This last edit looks more like vandalism than anything else...

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is your first application to the UK and perhaps your first trip outside of Philippines.

Your partner should prepare documents showing:

- His current status in the UK (as he is a UK citizen, a passport copy would suffice).
- Proof of income (for example, pay slips or tax returns).
- Proof of residence (for example, title deed to a property, rental contract, rental slips)
- Letter affirming the nature of your relationship, the length and purpose of your visit and specifically what costs he is willing to bear for your trip. For example, the letter can state he is covering your room and board, the cost of your flight, plus any daily expenses you may incur during your stay.

You should prepare the following documents, which are required for any standard visit visa application:

- Photographs with a white background.
- Copy and original of your passport - which should be valid for 6 months after your trip.
- Proof of employment, such as a salary certificate that details your length of employment, your position (job title), your salary.
- Bank statements showing income and expenses. Please do not try to "borrow" money for your trip just to inflate your bank balance. This is called funds parking is a very common reason for rejection of applications as it is considered a form of fraud.
- Application for a Standard Visit Visa
- Any fees
- Flight reservations for the duration of your trip

You can find out exactly what all documents are required from https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa including how and where to apply for your visa and any fees as well. This is an official UK government site - try to avoid others that may be scams just to charge you fees.

As you and your partner are not in a legal relationship (ie, you are not in a civil partnership) you can only apply for a visit visa.

Comment: Possibly also proof from his landlord / cottage owner that he is allowed to have a visitor for several months.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. i will make sure that I will take time to visit the website and browse through everything.